# Unable to create Spring AOP aspect on Spring Data JPA Repository when CGLIB proxies are used

Tags: spring-data, spring-aop, cglib

I'm trying to apply an aspect on a Spring Data JPA Repository and it works fine with default Spring AOP config

`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

(when Spring uses standard Java interface-based proxies).

However, when I switch to CGLIB proxies:

`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`

I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59]:
```

Looks like Spring tries to wrap a CGLIB proxy on a repository class, which is already a CGLIB proxy (generated by Spring Data) and fails.

Any ideas how to make it work?

My Spring Data Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DummyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<DummyEntity, Integer> {
}
```

and the aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class DummyCrudRepositoryAspect {

    @After("this(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)")
    public void onCrud(JoinPoint pjp)  {
       System.out.println("I'm there!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your analysis is correct - any time a CGLIB proxy is applied to an already proxied object, the proxy generation operation fails.  This problem exists in many places within the Spring framework.  It seems that [a fix](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12870) has been applied for the upcoming 4.2 release.  Can you try with a snapshot version of 4.2 binaries to see if it fixes your particular case?

Comment: thanks @manish, I'll check with latest Spring version

Comment: Great, please put an updated comment with your results here once you have run your tests.  Many of us have similar requirements and awaiting a fix on the JIRA I pointed to.

Comment: @manish, I've tried the latest Spring milestone 4.2.0.RC2 and it solved my problem. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Bartek.